# 504 Gateway Time-Out 240000 ms when using EventSource

Tags: node.js, azure, spring-boot, websocket

I'm using this `node.js` [library](https://github.com/fanout/reconnecting-eventsource) in order to `Reconnect` to an `EventSource` in case it closes.

### The Problem

My web app is hosted on Microsoft Azure , in which i've enabled `Web Sockets`

After `240000ms` the event source object closes with a 504 Gateway time-out error.

[image]

### Web app architecture:

The project is designed with the `Spring boot` framework and this is one of my **Streaming Endpoints**

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/completed/receive", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Event> receiveCompleted() {
    
            return Flux.create(sink -> {
            completedProcessor.register(sink::next);
        });
    }
```

### Headers I've tried and didn't work

- `Connection : Keep-Alive`
- `Keep - Alive: timeout=500000`

### Enable Web Sockets from Microsoft Azure

[image]

### How i'm listening to the endpoint with JS

```html
var eventSourceCompleted;
        
eventSourceCompleted =  new ReconnectingEventSource("/api/completed/receive");

        

// Receive messages
eventSourceCompleted.onmessage = function (evt) {
//Do Something

};
eventSourceCompleted.onerror = function (e) {
      console.log("EventSource failed: " + e);
};
```

No matter what i try, 240k ms later the connection closes, how can that be?

Comment: Your question is very complicated. I have two ideas, we can refer to them together.

Comment: 1. First of all, it is recommended to add a log to the program, check the running status of the program on the portal, and the log before and after the error is reported.

Comment: 2. It is recommended to submit issues on github and submit the specific phenomenon of your problem. It may be that there is such a bug in their current version.

Comment: I personally believe that it's not a library related issue, `new EventSource()` in `<script>`  has this weird behavior by it self , `new ReconnectingEventSource()` uses `new EventSource()` in it's source code. Bottom line if  `new EventSource()` can't reconnect then this library won't work as well. In `localhost` it works , on Azure it does not.

Comment: Check the log in the portal, can you see any error messages?

Comment: Portal logs are not enabled yet. I can access the front-end log instead. I can proceed and enable them otherwise

Comment: Keep in mind that the first connection `new ReconnectingEventSource()` plays well with no fatal exception

Comment: @PhillAlexakis Did you fix this problem? I have the same with spring, angular and nginx, http works fine only https does not works :/